# Why does the "Back" button refresh the current page and how do I stop it?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using the latest version of Chrome on the latest update of Windows 7. This happens on both my laptop and my desktop.

I'll go "Back" and the same page just reloads, and then when I press and hold on the back button, I see that the page has loaded multiple times, sometimes so many that the entire ten or so entries are filled up with the same page.

This started happening recently and I started to realize that some sites do this and some don't, which make me wonder if this is some sort of cookie or javascript code. I only use three addons; ABP, Chrome to Phone, and Reddit Enhancement Suite.

I unfortunately don't have a specific site that this happens on off the top of my head and it hasn't yet happened today, so perhaps this is more of a theoretical question.

Is it possible for a web site to modify what my back button does? Or could it be something else I am doing? It's really annoying because I have dedicated back/forward buttons on my desktop mouse and three-finger gestures for my laptop's touchpad that go back and forward, and they're really convenient but I've stopped using them because it doesn't consistently work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Website, generally Javascript issue.

Options -

1. Stop going to sites you know do this.
2. Look for browser extensions that block this behavior
3. Use debug to delete the part of the JavaScript that is breaking the back button.
4. Middle click or right-click -> open new tab for links. Instead of going back, kill that tab.